# Angular Mathjax <math> "Unexpected text node: '\frac{M_p}{M_r} \times 100%'"

Tags: javascript, mathjax

Good evening all,

I'm trying to render Mathjax content in my application.

As an example I'm trying to load `<math>\(\frac{M_p}{M_r} \times 100%\)</math>` but it's resulting in an "Unexpected text node" error.

Editing the source will result in having to change with regex as there's 1000's of entries so doing it individually and don't want to. I know the code works as the wfExtension for mathjax renders this style of input perfectly.

I have am loading the script dynamically, I've tried a number of options but now reached the point where I'm throwing everything in to it (see below).

```
    loadScript() {
      let node = document.createElement('script');
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
      node.innerHTML = `MathJax.Hub.Config({
   config: ["MMLorHTML.js"],
  jax: ["input/TeX","input/MathML","input/AsciiMath","output/HTML-CSS","output/NativeMML", "output/PreviewHTML"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mml2jax.js","asciimath2jax.js","MathMenu.js","MathZoom.js", "fast-preview.js", "AssistiveMML.js", "a11y/accessibility-menu.js"],
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","noErrors.js","noUndefined.js"]
  }
});`;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node); 
    }
```

Any advice?

Thank you,

Edit following Davide Cervone comment:
Still getting the issue. It now claims the added char's are now part of the Unexpected Text Node.

Snapshot from Webpage:
[image]

Mathjax MathML Code:
[image]

Headers (for proof):
[image]

HTML Code:
[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: The `<math>` tag indicates MathML content, not TeX notation.  Use `\(...\)` for inline-math and `\[...\]` or one of the AMS equation environments to do display-style math.  Also, you don't need any of the `jax`, `extensions`, or `TeX` blocks in your configuration expect for the `AsciiMath` ones, if you really intend to use them.  The `TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML` already includes all of that.

Comment: @DavideCervone, thank you, I've implemented your advice and still getting the above. I was under the impression MathML used $....$ notation and LaTex was as per the above. Thank you for setting me straight. I have updated the above. Still no joy. Thank you.

Comment: Do not put `<math>...</math>` around your `\(...\)`.  That indications that the content is MathML, and that is what is causing the error, since you can't have (non-space) text inside `<math>...</math>` unless it is inside a token element like `<mi>`.  But you are not entering MathML, so don't use `<math>...</math>`.   Just use `\(...\)`.